# Save elements of a list to ".Rda" file inside a function

Tags: r, environment, rdata

Just for example, I have a dataframe with columns: `name`, `n`, `mean` and `sd`. How do I extract and then save the elements of a list into a single `rda` file. The file should contain the generated datasets and not the list.

```
random.r <- function(df, filename) {
  save.random <- function(name, n, mean, sd) {
    rn <- rnorm(n=n, mean=mean, sd=sd)
    assign(deparse(name), rn)
  }

  rlist <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) 
    save.random(df$name[x], df$n[x],df$mean[x],df$sd[x],simplify = FALSE))
  save(list = rlist, file = paste(filename,".Rda",sep=""), envir = .GlobalEnv)    
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Are your code blocks attempts at doing what you're requesting help with? Not sure what you intend `random.r` to do, exactly.

Comment: @jbaums yes, just modified the code to make it simpler as it involved a lot of equations. i would want to have 'save' to include only the rlist elements and not the list itself.

Comment: @jbaums my apologies. have edited the code to reflect just one function. Adjusted the encapsulation as random.r and rlist appears to be different functions. rlist is within random.r

Comment: Thanks for correcting the code - I've edited my answer, which should now solve your problem. There were a couple of issues with your code: elements of `rlist` were not being named correctly; the vector of element names to save was not specified correctly; and the search environment was wrong.

Comment: @jbaum lack of sleep makes me dizzy and confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to tell R where to find the objects referred to in `save`. To do this, provide the list itself as an environment:

```
save(list=names(rlist), file=..., envir=as.environment(rlist))
```

Note also that `list` must be a vector of object names, so this should be `names(rlist)`, not simply `rlist`, since the latter is a list of numeric vectors.

The following is a modification of your `random.r`, which works as you had intended. At the end of this post I also provide simplified code that achieves the same.

```
random.r <- function(df, filename) {
  save.random <- function(name, n, mean, sd) {
    rnorm(n=n, mean=mean, sd=sd)
  }

  rlist <- setNames(lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) {
    save.random(df$name[x], df$n[x], df$mean[x], df$sd[x])
  }), df$name)
  save(list = names(rlist), file = paste0(filename, ".rda"), 
       envir = as.environment(rlist))    
}
```

The key changes above are the specification of `names(rlist)` as the list (vector) of element names that you want to save, and `as.environment(rlist)` as the environment in which you want R to search for objects with those names. Note also that I've used `setNames` to correctly assign elements of `df$name` as the names of the resulting elements of `rlist`.

A simplified version would be:

```
rlist <- setNames(mapply(rnorm, d$n, d$mean, d$sd), d$name)
save(list=names(rlist), file='~/../Desktop/foo.rda', 
     envir=as.environment(rlist))
```

where `d` is your `data.frame`. Here, `mapply` is a handy shortcut; it steps through the vectors `d$n`, `d$mean` and `d$sd` simultaneously, performing `rnorm` each time.

The simplified code can of course be wrapped into a function if you require, e.g.:

```
f <- function(x, filename) {
  rlist <- setNames(mapply(rnorm, x$n, x$mean, x$sd), x$name)
  save(list=names(rlist), file=paste0(filename, '.rda'), 
       envir=as.environment(rlist))
}

d <- data.frame(name=LETTERS, n=sample(100, 26), mean=runif(26), sd=runif(26),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

f(d, '~/../Desktop/foo')
```